# Need find by: By.CLASS_NAME returns True or False results with selenium

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I want to find the class name named: Form_error__34nSh
-If found, return True
-If not found, return False
I use: `driver.find_element(By.CLASS_NAME, "Form_error__34nSh")`
it works in case of cost at Class_name
but get error in case class_name does not exist. and the program is discontinued
`selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"css selector","selector":".Form_error__34nSh"}`
Please help me answer.
I'm self-studying selenium on the internet.
Thank for reading

Comment: Use try-except. See https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/errors.html#handling-exceptions

Answer (score 0):

Changing the `find_element` to `find_elements` will do the charm.
`find_elements` returns a list of found matches, so in case of match(es) it will be a non-empty list interpreted by Python as a Boolean True while in case of no match it will return you an empty list interpreted by Python as a Boolean False.
So your code could be as simple as:

```py
return driver.find_elements(By.CLASS_NAME, "Form_error__34nSh")
```